# JavaScript -TypeError when I use underscore in naming object array and in get and set method

Tags: javascript

I have completed a JS project that creates a menu, populates it with appetizers, mains and desserts including their price and stores in arrays in menu object.
A random selection of appetizers, mains and desserts can be called along with the total price of the meal.

This code works fine but it is not what i want:

```
const menu = {
  _courses: {
    appetizers: [],
    mains:[],
    desserts:[]
  },
  get appetizers(){
    return this._courses.appetizers;
  },
  get mains(){
    return this._courses.mains;
  },
  get desserts(){
    return this._courses.desserts;
  },
  set appetizers(appetizers) {
    this._courses.appetizers = appetizers;
  },
  set mains(mains) {
    this._courses.mains = mains;
  },
  set desserts(desserts) {
    this._courses.desserts = desserts;
  },
  get courses() {
    return {
      appetizers: this._courses.appetizers,
      mains: this._courses.mains,
      desserts: this._courses.desserts
    };
    },

    addDishToCourse(courseName, dishName, dishPrice) {
      let dish = {
        name: dishName,
        price: dishPrice
      };

      this._courses[courseName].push(dish);
    },

    getRandomDishFromCourse(courseName) {
      let dishes = this._courses[courseName];
      let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * dishes.length);
      return dishes[randomIndex];
    },

generateRandomMeal() {    
    let appetizer = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('appetizers');
    let main = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('mains');
    let dessert = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('desserts');
    let totalCost = appetizer.price + main.price + dessert.price;
    
    return `Your meal is ${appetizer.name}, ${main.name} and ${dessert.name} and it costs £${totalCost.toFixed(2)}.`;
    },

};

menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'prawncocktail', 4.75);
menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'soup', 3.77);
menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'bread and butter', 1.25);

menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'steak', 11.75);
menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'vegetarian', 9.75);

menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'ice cream', 3.99);
menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'cheese and biscuits', 2.99);

let meal = menu.generateRandomMeal();
console.log(meal);
```

I want **_appetizers: []** **not appetizers: []**

I have tried to find online documentation to help but so far have failed!

Adding the underscore "_" to appetizers **_appetizers** in _courses and in the get and set methods causes an error.

This code throws a TypeError

```
const menu = {
  _courses: {
    _appetizers: [],
    mains:[],
    desserts:[]
  },
  get appetizers(){
    return this._courses._appetizers;
  },
  get mains(){
    return this._courses.mains;
  },
  get desserts(){
    return this._courses.desserts;
  },
  set appetizers(appetizers) {
    this._courses._appetizers = appetizers;
  },
  set mains(mains) {
    this._courses.mains = mains;
  },
  set desserts(desserts) {
    this._courses.desserts = desserts;
  },
  get courses() {
    return {
      appetizers: this._courses._appetizers,
      mains: this._courses.mains,
      desserts: this._courses.desserts
    };
    },

    addDishToCourse(courseName, dishName, dishPrice) {
      let dish = {
        name: dishName,
        price: dishPrice
      };

      this._courses[courseName].push(dish);
    },

    getRandomDishFromCourse(courseName) {
      let dishes = this._courses[courseName];
      let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * dishes.length);
      return dishes[randomIndex];
    },

generateRandomMeal() {    
    let appetizer = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('appetizers');
    let main = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('mains');
    let dessert = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('desserts');
    let totalCost = appetizer.price + main.price + dessert.price;
    
    return `Your meal is ${appetizer.name}, ${main.name} and ${dessert.name} and it costs £${totalCost.toFixed(2)}.`;
    },

};

menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'prawncocktail', 4.75);
menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'soup', 3.77);
menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'bread and butter', 1.25);

menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'steak', 11.75);
menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'vegetarian', 9.75);

menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'ice cream', 3.99);
menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'cheese and biscuits', 2.99);

let meal = menu.generateRandomMeal();
console.log(meal);
```

Error:

````
/home/ccuser/workspace/learn-javascript-objects-meal-maker/app.js:39
      this._courses[courseName].push(dish);
                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at Object.addDishToCourse (/home/ccuser/workspace/learn-javascript-objects-meal-maker/app.js:39:32)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the underscore when you call `addDishToCourse` as well:

```
menu.addDishToCourse('_appetizers', 'prawncocktail', 4.75);
menu.addDishToCourse('_appetizers', 'soup', 3.77);
menu.addDishToCourse('_appetizers', 'bread and butter', 1.25);
```

Otherwise, `courseName` is 'appetizers' (no underscore) and accessing `this._courses[courseName] = this._courses['appetizers']` results in undefined:

```
this._courses['appetizers'].push(dish);
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: ok thank you - i see now ( having run it with commented out get and set methods) that they are not part of the flow.

Answer (score 0):

You're using 'appetizers' as the key here:

```
menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'prawncocktail', 4.75);
```

, but the `_courses` object doesn't have it. You can change it to '_appetizers'.